# Edit htaccess file in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, .htaccess

I would like to deny all IP addresses but allow one specific IP address in `.htaccess`.

How I should configure my `.htaccess` or is it a different file?

I have CentOS 5 and Apache.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Directory /directory_name>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 1.2.3.4
</Directory>
```

Comment: Small note: This won't work in an `.htaccess` file but only in the main Apache httpd configuration. If you want to use the snipper in an `.htaccess` file you'll have to drop the `<Directory>` tags.